# Cypher Query Take long time to execute to find end node

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Actually While i am running my query at time not getting any result, even exception or error. Then query continues running and make deadlock.

I am using `neo4j`

```
MATCH p=(a:player{id:"500025"})-[:ADDRESS*]->(b:player)
WHERE NOT ((b)-[:ADDRESS]->()) AND (b.playerId = a.playerId)
WITH relationships(p) AS consRel, length(p) AS size, nodes(p) AS consAct
RETURN DISTINCT consAct AS activities,  consRel AS relationships
```

Comment: query is working but its take long time to execute then going in deadlock after a hour

Comment: While my answer is a reasonable guess, you'll need to provide more info in order for others to make more informed answers. Please provide info about your data model, and (after adding a reasonable upper bound on your var-length relationship) perform a PROFILE of the query, and after expanding all plan elements (the double-down arrow button in the lower right corner of the result pane) add the query plan to your description.

Answer (score 1):

Add an upper bound on your variable-length relationship, more  than likely the number of possible paths skyrocketed and made much more work than the db could handle (you may also want to check your memory config settings, in case heap or pagecache is too low).

You can check to see how many paths are being built up:

```
MATCH p=(a:player{id:"500025"})-[:ADDRESS*..10]->(b:player)
WHERE NOT ((b)-[:ADDRESS]->()) AND (b.playerId = a.playerId)
RETURN count(p)
```

See how the count increases as you increase the upper bound of your var-length relationship. More than likely the number of paths is pushing into the millions or higher as the upper bound increases. You should probably pick a reasonable upper bound and stick to that instead.

Comment: actually i need to find end node  p=(a:player{id:"500025"})-[:ADDRESS*..10]->(b:player) so i used this p=(a:player{id:"500025"})-[:ADDRESS*]->(b:player)

Comment: and i have high config memory

Comment: The point was to illustrate that this approach may not be feasible. Please observe the counts as you increase your upper bound. Then you may see (if I'm right) that without an upper bound this query may not ever work to completion.

Comment: Is :player(playerId) unique in your graph? And if not, for the given player `a` how many :player nodes are there with the same `playerId`?

Comment: actually i have total 4000+ data in neo4j